# Is It Correct Practice to Require SaveChanges to be Explicitly Called in my Repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

I am currently implementing a [repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) in my MVC 3 application. All the repository methods that I am implementing that change the data in some way (Add* and Delete*, primarily) currently DO NOT call the SaveChanges method. I explicitly require the user of my repository to do this.

The other option, of course, is that I always call SaveChanges in my mutation methods.

What tends to be the best practice here and why? I've been doing it the first way long enough that I have become used to it, but I'm curious if there is a reason the second would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a unit of work from a business or use case perspective involves modifications of many data entities.

You really want to store all the modifications in a transaction or none of them if something fails while submitting.

So its a good idea to call SaveChanges only once at the end of your unit of work and not  inside your Add, Update and Delete methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are good reasons for doing it either way. However, it's important that you make it known if your mutation methods do not persist changes to the database. What I'll do is provide overloads that allows the callers to specify. Also, providing the overloads makes it very clear via intellisense (if we can assume everybody's IDE has that feature in 2012) that there is an overload for each of those methods. Otherwise, you'll be depending on the users of your repository to read your documentation (and nobody does that anymore, right?).